# How can I fill a TableViewCell with an array that comes from web service?

Tags: arrays, swift, rest, uitableview

I need to fill a TableViewCell with info stored in an array that is conformed with the data I brought from a REST API. I was trying to make one class for each specific category of the array from the service, and then put this array on a 'for loop' to then try to fill the TableViewCell. But I think that I'm declaring my parameters incorrectly because I'm having many errors.

The classes I conform are:

```
class CouponDesc : AnyObject {
    var description: String

    init(description: String) {
        self.description = description
    }
}

class CouponCat : AnyObject {
    var category: String

    init(category: String) {
        self.category = category
    }
}

class CouponTitle : AnyObject {
    var title: String

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

The categories I need to bring from the web service are: Title, Description and Category from a coupon, so that's why I made those classes.

The `for` loop I'm making is this:

```
for index in mainCoupon {
    let description = (mainCoupon[index as! Int] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "promoDescription") as! String
    let newCoupon = CouponDesc(description: description)
    self.couponsDesc.append(newCoupon)
}

for index in mainCoupon {
    let title = (mainCoupon[index as! Int] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "nameStore") as! String
    let newCoupon = CouponTitle(title: title)
    self.couponsTitle.append(newCoupon)
}

for index in mainCoupon {
    let category = (mainCoupon[index as! Int] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "category") as! String
    let newCoupon = CouponCat(category: category)
    self.couponsCat.append(newCoupon)
}
```

The `mainCoupon` is the array that comes from the REST API:

```
let miURL = URL(string: RequestConstants.requestUrlBase)
let request =  NSMutableURLRequest(url: miURL!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: miURL! as URL) {
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
        let parseJSON = json
        let object = parseJSON?["object"] as! NSDictionary
        let mainCoupon = object["mainCoupon"] as! NSArray
```

I think that my mistake is in this section:

```
let category = (mainCoupon[index as! Int] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "category") as! String
```

because I'm not sure how I have to assign that category to the coupon's array. At last, where I assign the array to the TableViewCell is here:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell

    cell.couponImg.image = couponsImg[indexPath.row]
    cell.couponTitle.text = couponsTitle[indexPath.row] as AnyObject as? String
    cell.couponDescription.text = couponsDesc[indexPath.row] as AnyObject as? String
    cell.couponCategory.text = couponsCat[indexPath.row] as AnyObject as? String

    return cell
}
```

Also I'm not sure that I'm putting the correct value to the cell:

```
cell.couponTitle.text = couponsTitle[indexPath.row] as AnyObject as? String'
```

I don't know if this is the best way.

The error I'm receiving is:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x10a1aa2b0) to 'NSNumber' (0x1093a14a8).

And it's because of this line:

```
let description = (mainCoupon[index as! Int] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "promoDescription") as! String'
```

The Class of my TableViewCell is this:

```
class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var couponImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var couponTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var couponDescription: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var starButtons: [UIButton]!
    @IBOutlet weak var couponCategory: UILabel!
```

[image: REST Example]

Comment: I think you should put a screenshot of that API, because we can't tell which type is the value for each key in that dictionary..

Comment: The type of the three keys is a String.

Comment: if `let object = parseJSON?["object"] as! NSDictionary` the value of each key inside that object `Dictionary` is String, so why this ` object["mainCoupon"] as! NSArray`. Putting a sample of that REST API data would help us help you :)

Comment: Ok, I shared you a sample of that REST, the only thing is that the language is Spanish, but hope that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for subclassing AnyObject here `class CouponDesc : AnyObject`.

No need to have 3 different objects to store your data; your data is simple not complex. However if you want, you can still use three objects but you should group them later on like:

```
class CouponMainDescription {
  let desc: CouponDesc
  let title: CouponTitle
  // on and on 
}
```

I will use a simple `struct with a failable init` which will `return nil` if one of the key's value is nil

```
struct CouponDescription {
    let stars:Int
    let distance:Double
    let address:String
    // do the same for other data members 
    init?(_ dict:[String:Any]?) {
          guard let _dict = dict,
                let stars = _dict["stars"] as? Int,
                let distance = _dict["distance"] as? Double,
                let address = _dict["address"] as? String
            else { return nil }

        self.stars = stars
        self.distance = distance
        self.address = address

    }
}



let arrCoupons = [CouponDescription?]() //<<-- we have an array to populate your tableView
```

> In your parsing method

after this

```
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]

    let mainCoupons = json["mainCoupon"] as? NSArray //<-- mainCoupons is an array of object/ dictionary so 

   let arr = mainCoupon.map({ CouponDescription($0 as? [String:Any])})
```

> instead of using a for Loop, using `map` we'd take each object of that mainCoupons Array and transform each object to CouponDescription Object, and the result will be append to  `arr` which is the same type with `arrCoupons`, finally assign arr to arrCoupons & reload your tableView

or even using flatMap to remove the optional (which is better in this case)

```
 let arr = mainCoupon.flatMap({ CouponDescription($0 as? [String:Any])})
```

> where `arr` is a type of `[CouponDescription]` not `[CouponDescription?]`, thus change this `let arrCoupons = [CouponDescription?]()` to `let arrCoupons = [CouponDescription]()`

Comment: But how can I assign the fields to the array? In your example I don't see where you are assigning the mainCoupon["category"] or mainCoupon["description"]?... Also I don't know how can I pass this array to my cell?

Comment: just declare them in the struct just like I did for `stars, address, distance`

Comment: This doesn't help me if I cannot assign this array to my TableViewCell. In this cell I have three labels, that's why I use 3 objects, because I need one array per label. But the way you show me doesn't help me assigning this arrays to my cell. I did it this way: 'var arrCouponsName = [CouponName]()'  and in the func getCoupons() = 'self.arrCouponsName = mainCoupon.flatMap({CouponName($0 as? [String:Any])})' at last, at mi func cellForRowAtIndexPath = 'cell.couponTitle.text = arrCouponsName[indexPath.row]' But I got this error: 'Cannot assign value of type HomeVC.CouponName to type String'

Comment: I assure you the way I show you worked, after assigning `arr` to `arrCoupons`, your rest api data is inside of that array, and yes you could do `arrCoupons[indexPath.row]` to access each member of that couponDescription, you don't need 3 objects, add your tableView code to the question so i can take a look at it

Comment: And I did it assigning arr to arrCoupons but I'm still receiving the same error: 'Cannot assign value of type HomeViewController.CouponDescription to type String'

Comment: arr cannot be a String unless you have some global variable of type string, I think you should comment out all the code you have, start with the parsing print out the `arr` you will see that the REST API data is in `arr`, then do `arrCoupons = arr`, make sure your tableView return the number of rows based on arrCoupons

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149413/discussion-between-zita-noriega-estrada-and-lamar).